# Как заставить Eclipse проверять код в соответствии с -std=c++17

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++17

Зашёл в настройки проекта, C/C++ Build, Settings, GCC C++ Compiler, Dialect, Language Standart  и установил ISO C++17 (-std=c++17), но Eclipse игнорирует эти настройки когда проверяет код и подчёркивает "незнакомые" ему элементы языка. Например в 17м стандарте есть возможность доверить компилятору выводить тип шаблонного класса в зависимости от переданных в конструктор аргументов, типа: "std::pair p(5,true);"

При нажатии кнопки Build - код с такими элементами компилируется и запускается, и отлаживается... но, сам Eclipse подчёркивает "незнакомые" ему элементы языка...

Существует ли возможность заставить Eclipse проверять код в соответствии с нужным мне 17м стандартом?

Если да, то как?

Comment: Нет, в Eclipse поддержка семантического разбора С++ неполноценна (даже без С++17).

Comment: @user7860670, что можно заюзать вместо Eclipse'a? (Не VS)